# How to change colour text from a tkinter.button

Tags: python, button, text, colors, tkinter

I am working in python and I need to change the colour text from a Tkinter.button, but I don't know any additional parameter, attached you may find small fragment code:

```
btn_enter = Tkinter.Button(root, text = "Show graphic", width=20, bg = '#DC143C', relief=RAISED)
```

Thanxxxs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `fg` argument:

```
btn_enter = Tkinter.Button(all_your_args, fg=your_desired_value)
```

It changes the foreground colour, which is simply the text here.

Comment: @user3596749 Glad I could help. If my answer was helpful to you, would you mind accepting it? You can do it by clicking on the tick below the vote counts so that it stays green. Thank you.